# Who and when did this bid'ah for the first time in adhan?

Tags: shia-sunni, bidah, adhan

In Sunni Islam adhan (اذان) is as follows:

> اَللهُ اَکبَر (4 times)
>
> اَشهَدُ اَن لا اِلَهَ اِلَّا الله (2 times)
>
> اَشهَدُ اَنَّ مُحَمَّد رَسُولُ الله (2 times)
>
> حَیِّ عَلَی الصَّلاة (2 times)
>
> حَیِّ عَلَی الفَلاح (2 times)
>
> حَیِّ عَلَی خَیرِالعَمَل (1 time)
>
> اَللهُ اَکبَر (2 times)
>
> لا اِلَهَ اِلّا الله (2 times)

But in Shia Islam there are execssive parts between two of the parts:

> اَشهَدُ اَنَّ مُحَمَّد رَسُولُ الله (2 times)
>
> **اَشهَدُ اَنَّ عَلِی وَلیُ الله** (1 time)
>
> **اَشهَدُ اَنَّ عَلِی حُجَّةُ الله** (1 time)
>
> حَیِّ عَلَی الصَّلاة (2 times)

The adhan that was recited by the Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H.) and his companions clearly was the Sunni version.

But somewhere in history Shiites did this bid'ah in adhan. Now in Iran I know the Shiite version is recited.

Who and when did this bid'ah?

Answer (score 0):

Salam,

In shia Islam , there are five pillars of Islam :  **tawhid** ( monotheism), **adl** ( belief in the divine justice of Allah), **Nubuwat** (prophethood) , **Imamate** ( succession to prophet Muhammad) and **Qiyamat** ( day of judgement/resurrection).

Since *Imamat* is considered to be one of the founding pillars of Shia Islam , hence it is **recommended** ( not compulsory) to include it in adhan after testifying the prophethood of prophet Muhammad.

> The adhan that was recited by the Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H.) and his companions clearly was the Sunni version.

Indeed the part testifying the *wilayah* was not recited in adhan in Prophet's time. This is the exact reason which is why the wilayah part in not considered compulsory (but recommended) in shia adhan and hence is not a bidah ( which means that you can now edit some wordings from your questions now ).

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I mistakenly had accepted your answer. My question was *who* and *when* added those parts to adhan. I know Imamate is one of the pillars of Shiite. But for sure there was a *person* who first introduced those parts with those wordings (ولی & حجة) for the first time.

Comment: @EtackSxchange I would need to search for the history though. I would update you with an edit.